# A cron job that calls a master script to call other scripts

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron

I have an application that dependes on checks every 45 minutes. These checks are set up by a cron jop, that calls a url on my server. This script then execute all the checks.

These checks became very dynamic and now I'm thinking of a better solution for this..

Now I need to break these checks into multiple URLs, and call multiple files, but I don't really want to deal with cron jobs for that all the time, is it possible that I have one PHP script to asynchronously call multiple other URLs when it's executed?

My main problem is that, these checks are not simple PHP files but full on routed URLs, running on a framework (Laravel), so I can't just run php CLI calls..

How could I achieve that?

Comment: you could look into curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could abstract all of these processes to a `Job` or a `Command`. This way you can still execute them individually from your controllers or you to group them all together.

Furthermore, what you're describing sounds like a textbook use case for `Task scheduling` in Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling.

Hope this helps!